# Quirks of my first Logistic Regression model; Boolean warnings, all-or-nothing predictions, ill-defined F Statistic

Tags: regression, logistic

**The Setup**

I have a dataframe `df3` which contains film information (`Budget, Year, Runtime, IMDB (score)`) and a personal rating (integer between 0 and 10 inclusive). I'm trying to teach myself data science and use it for various models. This is my attempt at using it for a simple logisitic regression model.

For my first step I create a new column called `Cinema` which assigns 0s to every entry with a rating below a 6 and 1 to those above it.

```
df3["Cinema"] = np.where(df3["Rating"] > 6, 1, 0)
```

Next I split my data into test/train sets.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(dtX, df3["Cinema"], test_size=0.25, random_state=16)
```

dtX is a list of column headers I borrowed from the attempt at making a decision tree.

```
features = ['Budget', 'Year', 'Runtime', 'IMDB']
dtX = df3[features]
```

Then I run my model on the training set and predict Cinema values.

```
logr = linear_model.LogisticRegression(random_state=16)
logr.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = logr.predict(X_test)
```

Finally I create a confusion matrix and the accuracy report.

```
confusion_matrix = metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
cm_display = metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix = confusion_matrix, display_labels = [False, True])
cm_display.plot()
plt.show()

print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
```

**The problems**

During my first few runs, I would sometimes get the warning:

```
Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

I ran the line `bool(y_train)` to see what happened and got the warning, but after that it never reappeared. I suspected that how I created the Cinema column was throwing it, but why would it stop being a problem?

The next, and bigger, problem is that my model only predicts False values when the threshold value for Cinema is 6, and only predicts positive values when it's 5.

With 6

```
          precision    recall  f1-score   support

       0       0.58      1.00      0.74       120
       1       0.00      0.00      0.00        86
accuracy                           0.58       206
```

vs with 5

```
          precision    recall  f1-score   support

       0       0.00      0.00      0.00        63
       1       0.69      1.00      0.82       143
accuracy                           0.69       206
```

The distribution of 0s and 1s in the training and testing sets are reasonably balanced, with the worst iteration being: 1    143, 0     63

Running the classification report also gives this warning, which I'm guessing is a product of the one sided classification probabilities.

```
UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples. Use `zero_division` parameter to control this behavior.
  _warn_prf(average, modifier, msg_start, len(result))
```

Any ideas on why the model is so sensitive to the threshold value? I've also noticed that reducing the number of columns in Features doesn't seem to influence the T/F balance at all, it's solely determined by the threshold.

**Edit**

I toyed around with the model some more and I think I discovered the reason for the poor model performance; my data is rubbish. I tried to run a decision tree and got an accuracy of 0 on both the testing and training models. I then tried dropping some of my predicting variables and I was able to get a believable confusion matrix when only the IMDB score was included. Since I'd expect this to be more correlated with the personal Rating than any other metric, I think this means that the other variables simply have no predicting power.

I'd still like to know though why this manifested as extreme probabilities depending on the threshold though!

Comment: Welcome to CV. Some of these are software problems that would be better addressed in another forum such as [SO].  The underlying statistical problem seems to be [complete separation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=complete+separation), but that's just a guess because there's not enough information here to determine that.  Please explore the link to our related threads.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the suggestions. What information can I provide that would help determine if complete separation is occurring? I have looked at some explanations of this phenomenon and it's not immediately obvious to me from looking at the distribution of my data why it would happen. I have also added some more information just now about some new behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to produce a more credible confusion matrix by scaling my data using

```
scaledX = scale.fit_transform(dtX)
```

After dropping out some variables I believe the problem was the Budget entry, which contained values many times larger than those of the other columns.